# Fake scrolling using touchmove

Tags: javascript, touch

I am trying to scroll a given page that only supports touch events but I havent been able to get it working. I am using https://news.google.com/ to test by emulating an iPad device. Using the chrome touch emulation I am able to scroll the content on the page perfectly fine, however I have been unable to scroll by dispatching Touch events.

This is my sample code:

```js
var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

var mw = w / 2;
var mh = h / 2;

var tstart = new Touch({
  identifier: 0,
  target: document.documentElement,
  clientX: mw,
  clientY: mh,
  screenX: mw,
  screenY: mh,
  pageX: mw,
  pageY: mh,
  radiusX: 11.5,
  radiusY: 11.5,
  rotationAngle: 0,
  force: 1
});
document.dispatchEvent(new TouchEvent('touchstart', {
  bubbles: true,
  touches: [tstart],
  targetTouches: [tstart],
  changedTouches: [tstart]
}));

for (var i = 0, len = 100; i < len; i+=10)
{
  var tmove = new Touch({
    identifier: 0,
    target: document.documentElement,
    clientX: mw,
    clientY: mh - i,
    screenX: mw,
    screenY: mh - i,
    pageX: mw,
    pageY: mh - i,
    radiusX: 11.5,
    radiusY: 11.5,
    rotationAngle: 0,
    force: 1
  });
  document.dispatchEvent(new TouchEvent('touchmove', {
    bubbles: true,
    touches: [tmove],
    targetTouches: [tmove],
    changedTouches: [tmove]
  }));
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Note: Im not looking for cross-browser support, just support for Chrome.

Comment: Also, I have verified that the events are dispatching correctly using `window.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){console.log('move',e);}, true);`

Comment: I also tried using `document.elementFromPoint(mw, mh);` for the target rather than `document.documentElement` which also didnt work.